# Simple encrypt/decrypt functions in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, encryption

Are there any simple encrypt/decrypt functions in Classic ASP?

The data that needs to be encrypted and decrypted is not super sensitive. So simple functions would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4guysfromrolla.com: [RC4 Encryption Using ASP & VBScript](https://web.archive.org/web/20210728063606/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/010100-1.shtml)

See the attachments at the end of the page.

The page layout looks a bit broken to me, but all the info is there. I made it readable it by deleting the code block from the DOM via bowser development tools.

Comment: The more I thought about it.. My scenario is little more complex. Can you see if you can answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453908/key-management-classic-asp-encrypt-decrypt

Comment: @Broken Link: I don't see why using RC4 is not suitable for the scenario described. You need a shared secret between your two ASP pages (a common password) and then you will be able to determine if the encrypted message sent to the one page was generated by the other. The password must never be compromised of course, that's the only catch. P.S.: I'm not going to answer the other question to raise the chance that somebody else gives it a try.

Comment: That was my intention when I posted this question.But the issues is lets say I'm using RC4.. I encrypted some random key and sent it, then when I have to validate it, the RC4 will just decrypt the data what ever it is, it won't tell weather it was able to decrypt successfully or not. Since I'm not storing the generated key in first place, I don't know how if that was the key I generated or not.

Comment: @Broken Link: That's a general problem with encryption, not one with RC4. If you want the message recognizable, then you must make it recognizable. Don't use a random string, give it structure. Use the IP of the client, the current time, a fixed format, and then encrypt it. Encrypting a random string alone makes no sense at all. A structured string will look random enough after encryption, but after decryption you will be able to find out if it is bogus or not by comparing actual against expected structure.

Comment: The above algorithm works on their site (the example). When I download and run the scripts the encrypted and decrypted values does not match the example and hence the decrypted value does not match the original entered text. Not sure if the code is wrong or there is something else into it, that I am missing.

Comment: @JonnyBoy The answer is from 2010, and the linked page is from 2000 (I'm amazed that the link still works) and RC4 is not a secure encryption scheme anymore by any stretch of the definition. I wholeheartedly suggest that you look for different options for encryption instead of trying to fix this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
' Encrypt and decrypt functions for classic ASP (by TFI)

'********* set a random string with random length ***********
cryptkey = "GNQ?4i0-*\CldnU+[vrF1j1PcWeJfVv4QGBurFK6}*l[H1S:oY\v@U?i,oD]f/n8oFk6NesH--^PJeCLdp+(t8SVe:ewY(wR9p-CzG<,Q/(U*.pXDiz/KvnXP`BXnkgfeycb)1A4XKAa-2G}74Z8CqZ*A0P8E[S`6RfLwW+Pc}13U}_y0bfscJ<vkA[JC;0mEEuY4Q,([U*XRR}lYTE7A(O8KiF8>W/m1D*YoAlkBK@`3A)trZsO5xv@5@MRRFkt\"

'**************************** ENCRYPT FUNCTION ******************************

'*** Note: bytes 255 and 0 are converted into the same character, in order to
'*** avoid a char 0 which would terminate the string

function encrypt(inputstr)
        Dim i,x
        outputstr=""
        cc=0
        for i=1 to len(inputstr)
                x=asc(mid(inputstr,i,1))
                x=x-48
                if x<0 then x=x+255
                x=x+asc(mid(cryptkey,cc+1,1))
                if x>255 then x=x-255
                outputstr=outputstr&chr(x)
                cc=(cc+1) mod len(cryptkey)
        next
        encrypt=server.urlencode(replace(outputstr,"%","%25"))
end function

'**************************** DECRYPT FUNCTION ******************************

function decrypt(byval inputstr)
        Dim i,x
        inputstr=urldecode(inputstr)
        outputstr=""
        cc=0
        for i=1 to len(inputstr)
                x=asc(mid(inputstr,i,1))
                x=x-asc(mid(cryptkey,cc+1,1))
                if x<0 then x=x+255
                x=x+48
                if x>255 then x=x-255
                outputstr=outputstr&chr(x)
                cc=(cc+1) mod len(cryptkey)
        next
        decrypt=outputstr
end function

'****************************************************************************

Function URLDecode(sConvert)
  Dim aSplit
  Dim sOutput
  Dim I
  If IsNull(sConvert) Then
         URLDecode = ""
         Exit Function
  End If
  'sOutput = REPLACE(sConvert, "+", " ") ' convert all pluses to spaces
  sOutput=sConvert
  aSplit = Split(sOutput, "%") ' next convert %hexdigits to the character
  If IsArray(aSplit) Then
        sOutput = aSplit(0)
        For I = 0 to UBound(aSplit) - 1
          sOutput = sOutput &  Chr("&H" & Left(aSplit(i + 1), 2)) & Right(aSplit(i + 1), Len(aSplit(i + 1)) - 2)
        Next
  End If
  URLDecode = sOutput
End Function
```

Comment: I have tested this, but seem to get strange results - i encrypt and then decrypt and compare to the original password- and its not consistant. out of a few hundred - only a few were successfully decrypted to their original form, many came out to include funny characters, eg:  `t2E���6`

Comment: much the same - tried decrypt(encrypt("plaintext") and the result was not the plaintext

Answer (score 0):

I know is a bit late for BrokenLink, but for the record and others like me who were looking for the same.

I found this https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/crypt_aes_encrypt_file.asp.

It needs to install a chilkat ActiveX component on WindowsServer. But this inconvenient becomes convenient when looking resources and processing time.

Its very easy to use, and the given example is pretty clear. To make it your own, just change the "keyHex" variable value and voilá.

Comment: Chilkat is a paid component - $280 (perpetual license though)